# `useTheme` must be used within `NativeBaseConfigProvider`

Tags: node.js, npm

In my project I faced the above error can anyone tell me how to solve this error.

The error I faced is:

**Error: `useTheme` must be used within `NativeBaseConfigProvider`**

**This error is located at:**

```
in Container
in ProductContainer (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
```

**ProductContainer.js:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native'
import { Container, Header, Icon, Item, Input } from 'native-base';
import ProductList from './ProductList';
import SearchedProduct from './SearchedProducts';
const data = require('../../assets/data/products.json');
const ProductContainer = () => {
    const [products, setProducts ] = useState([]);
    const [productsFiltered, setProductsFiltered] = useState([]);
    const [focus, setFocus] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        setProducts(data);
        setProductsFiltered(data);
        setFocus(false);
        return () => {
            setProducts([])
            setProductsFiltered([])
            setFocus()
        }
    }, [])    
    const SearchProduct = (text) => {
        setProductsFiltered(
            products.filter((i) => i.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
        );
    }
    const openList = () => {
        setFocus(true);
    } 
    const onBlur = () => {
        setFocus(flase);
    }
    return (
        <Container>
            <View  style = {{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
                  <Input
                  width = "100%"
                  variant = "rounded"
                  placeholder="Search"
                  onFocus={openList}
                  onChangeText={(text) => SearchProduct(text)}
                  />                  
            </View>
            {focus == true ? (
                <SearchProduct 
                    productsFiltered={productsFiltered}
                />
            ) : (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Product Container</Text>
                <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                    <FlatList 
                        data={products}
                        numColumns={2}
                        renderItem={({item}) => <ProductList 
                        key={item.brand}
                        item={item}/>}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.brand}
                    />
                </View>
            </View> 
        )}        
        </Container>        
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
export default ProductContainer
```

**App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

//Screens
import Header from './Shared/Header'
import ProductContainer from './Screens/Products/ProductContainer'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Header />
          <ProductContainer />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

**package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "animal-feedmart",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "expo": "~44.0.0",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
        "native-base": "^3.3.7",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "17.0.1",
        "react-native": "0.64.3",
        "react-native-base": "^1.1.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.1",
        "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
        "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

Please can anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Basically the root component to render should be wrapped in `<NativeBaseProvider> ... </NativeBaseProvider>` . For `expo-router` you can create a `_layout.jsx` file in the `app` directory and use provider there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

in your app.js import NativeBaseProvider and wrap your other components with it

```
import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base';

return (
   <NativeBaseProvider>
      {Your other components}
   </NativeBaseProvider>
);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243433/discussion-on-answer-by-rodsar-usetheme-must-be-used-within-nativebaseconfigp). If you have a new problem, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you RodSar. I did what you said and it was ok!

Answer (score 3):

If you put in the native provider and it is still showing the error, please ensure to change your Header as native base removed it from v3 upward, use HStack instead and if you want to use the Header downgrade the native base version to v2.12.14

Answer (score 1):

**I have solved this in App.js**

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { NativeBaseProvider, extendTheme } from 'native-base';
```

Create a Theme

```
  const newColorTheme = {
    brand: {
      900: '#5B8DF6',
      800: '#ffffff',
      700: '#cccccc',
    },
  };

const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: newColorTheme,
});
```

and use on

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider theme={theme}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Header />
        <Main/>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me https://docs.nativebase.io/testing#page-title

MyTestfile-test.tsx

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { Test } from '../screens/Test';

import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base';

const inset = {
  frame: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 },
  insets: { top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
};

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const wrapper = render(
    <NativeBaseProvider initialWindowMetrics={inset}>
      <Test />
    </NativeBaseProvider>,
  );
  wrapper.findByText('Test');
});
```

Test.tsx

```
import { Text } from 'native-base';
import React from 'react';

export const Test = () => {
  return <Text testID='test'>Test</Text>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header />
        <ProductContainer />
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}
```