# Error while running test on Jest + React Testing Library with Error: `useTheme` must be used within `NativeBaseConfigProvider` in React Native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, native-base

Dear Community. I'm trying to test simple React Native component. On test running I get an error

Error: useTheme must be used within NativeBaseConfigProvider

I'm using Jest + React Native Testing Library for ui rendering.

As was mention in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540355/usetheme-must-be-used-within-nativebaseconfigprovider) post I have added NativeBaseProvider on the top level of my testing UI. Also [here](https://docs.nativebase.io/next/testing) is instruction from native-base how to make it in tests.

But error still there.

Jest config file

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'react-native',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'node', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^~assets(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/assets$1',
        '^~constants(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/constants$1',
        '^~components(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components$1',
        '^~ducks(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/ducks$1',
        '^~routes(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/constants/routes$1',
        '^~utils(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils$1',
        '^~api(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/api$1',
        '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|ogg)$':
            '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    },
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
        '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|ogg)$':
            '<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        'node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native(-.*)?|@react-native(-community)?|native-base)/)',
    ],
    reporters: ['default'],
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        '<rootDir>/src/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    ],
    coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'text', 'clover'],
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect'],
};
```

Jest setup file

```
import mockRNCNetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo/jest/netinfo-mock.js';

const mock = jest.requireMock('react-native-reanimated');

jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () => ({
    ...mock,
    useSharedValue: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(0),
    useAnimatedStyle: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({}),
    useAnimatedScrollHandler: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({}),
    createAnimatedComponent: component => jest.fn().mockReturnValue(component),
    __reanimatedWorkletInit: jest.fn(),
    ScrollView: 'ScrollView',
}));

jest.mock('@react-native-community/netinfo', () => mockRNCNetInfo);
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter');
jest.mock('react-native-fs', () => {
    return {
        mkdir: jest.fn(),
        moveFile: jest.fn(),
        copyFile: jest.fn(),
        pathForBundle: jest.fn(),
        pathForGroup: jest.fn(),
        getFSInfo: jest.fn(),
        getAllExternalFilesDirs: jest.fn(),
        unlink: jest.fn(),
        exists: jest.fn(),
        stopDownload: jest.fn(),
        resumeDownload: jest.fn(),
        isResumable: jest.fn(),
        stopUpload: jest.fn(),
        completeHandlerIOS: jest.fn(),
        readDir: jest.fn(),
        readDirAssets: jest.fn(),
        existsAssets: jest.fn(),
        readdir: jest.fn(),
        setReadable: jest.fn(),
        stat: jest.fn(),
        readFile: jest.fn(),
        read: jest.fn(),
        readFileAssets: jest.fn(),
        hash: jest.fn(),
        copyFileAssets: jest.fn(),
        copyFileAssetsIOS: jest.fn(),
        copyAssetsVideoIOS: jest.fn(),
        writeFile: jest.fn(),
        appendFile: jest.fn(),
        write: jest.fn(),
        downloadFile: jest.fn(),
        uploadFiles: jest.fn(),
        touch: jest.fn(),
        MainBundlePath: jest.fn(),
        CachesDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
        DocumentDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
        ExternalDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
        ExternalStorageDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
        TemporaryDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
        LibraryDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
        PicturesDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
    };
});

jest.mock('rn-fetch-blob', () => ({
    fs: {
        unlink: jest.fn(),
        writeFile: jest.fn(),
    },
    ios: {
        previewDocument: jest.fn(),
    },
    config: jest.fn(),
}))

global.__reanimatedWorkletInit = jest.fn();
```

My React Native Component

```
mport React, { memo, useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { Button, Heading, Text, Box, ScrollView } from 'native-base';
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/native';
import { Link, NavigationContext } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { schema } from './schemaSignIn';

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth: { isLoading }, common, home }) => ({
    isLoading,
    usersMeta: common.usersMeta,
    isCommonLoading: common.isLoading,
    userInfo: home.userInfo,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    getUsersMetadata,
    handleSignIn,
})(SignIn);

export function SignIn({
    isLoading,
    getUsersMetadata,
    isCommonLoading,
    handleSignIn,
    usersMeta,
}) {
    const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();

    const [serverError, setServerError] = useState(null);
    const navigation = useContext(NavigationContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!usersMeta) getUsersMetadata();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    const {
        handleSubmit,
        register,
        control,
        setValue,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm({
        mode: formModes.onTouched,
        reValidateMode: formModes.onChange,
        resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    });

    const onSubmit = async values => {
        handleSignIn({ values, keycloak, setServerError, navigation });
    };

    const handleFocus = () => {
        if (serverError) setServerError(null);
    };

    return isCommonLoading
        ? <FullScreenLoading/>
        : (
            <ScrollView
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                paddingX='30px'
                paddingBottom='10px'
                backgroundColor={colorNames.white}
            >
                <Box
                    justifyContent='space-between'
                    paddingTop='10px'
                    height='100%'
                    safeArea
                >
                    <Box
                        flexDirection='row'
                        alignItems='center'
                        justifyContent='space-between'
                    >
                        <Box
                            width='151px'
                            height='30px'
                        >
                            <ServiceLogo/>
                        </Box>
                        <Box flexDirection='row' alignItems='center'>
                            <YouthWorkIrelandLogo/>
                            <Text
                                marginLeft='8px'
                                fontSize='2xs'
                                color={colors.customColors.gray1}
                            >
                                Youth Work Ireland
                            </Text>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                    <Box paddingBottom='40px'>
                        <Box>
                            <Heading
                                size='xl'
                                color={colorNames.primary600}
                            >
                                Youth Club
                            </Heading>
                            <Text
                                fontSize='sm'
                                color={colorNames.muted500}
                            >
                                Log in to continue
                            </Text>
                        </Box>
                        <Box marginBottom='80px'>
                            <TextInput
                                id='email'
                                keyboardType='email-address'
                                placeholder='Enter email'
                                label='Email'
                                name='email'
                                isInvalid={!!errors.email}
                                control={control}
                                register={register}
                                setServerError={setServerError}
                                onFocus={handleFocus}
                                error={errors.email}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                id='password'
                                name='password'
                                control={control}
                                register={register}
                                type='password'
                                isInvalid={!!errors.password}
                                placeholder='Password'
                                label='Password'
                                onFocus={handleFocus}
                                isForgotPassword
                                isRequired
                                setValue={setValue}
                                error={errors.password}
                            />
                        </Box>
                        {serverError
                            && <Text
                                marginTop='20px'
                                marginBottom='20px'
                                fontSize='xs'
                                color={colorNames.error600}
                                alignSelf='center'
                                textAlign='center'
                            >
                                {serverError}
                            </Text>
                        }
                        <Button
                            onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                            isLoading={isLoading}
                            height='38px'
                            isDisabled={!isEmpty(errors) || isLoading}
                            data-testid='loginBtn'
                        >
                            Log In
                        </Button>
                        <Box
                            flexDirection='row'
                            justifyContent='center'
                            marginTop='10px'
                        >
                            <Text fontSize='xs' marginRight='10px'>
                                Don’t have an account?
                            </Text>
                            <Link
                                to={{ screen: authRouteNames.createAccount }}
                                style={{
                                    color: primaryColors.primary600,
                                    fontWeight: '700',
                                }}
                            >
                                Register
                            </Link>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                    <Box
                        flexDirection='row'
                        justifyContent='center'
                        alignItems='center'
                    >
                        <Text
                            fontWeight='300'
                            fontSize='8px'
                            color={colors.customColors.gray3}
                        >
                            Powered by:
                        </Text>
                        <Box
                            width='50px'
                            height='10px'
                            marginLeft='10px'
                        >
                            <Icon/>
                        </Box>
                        <Box
                            width='15px'
                            height='14px'
                            marginLeft='10px'
                        >
                            <Logo/>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </ScrollView>
        );
}
```

My test file

```
describe('SignIn component', () => {
    const server = setupServer(...handlers);

    const getUsersMetadata = jest.fn();
    const handleSignIn = jest.fn();
    const navigation = { navigate: jest.fn() };

    beforeAll(() => server.listen());

    afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());

    afterAll(() => server.close());

    test('Component rendering successfully', async () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(
            <NativeBaseProvider initialWindowMetrics={inset}>
                <ReactNativeKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloakService}>
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <SignIn
                            handleSignIn={handleSignIn}
                            getUsersMetadata={getUsersMetadata}
                            isCommonLoading={false}
                            isLoading={false}
                            usersMeta={{}}
                            navigation={navigation}
                        />
                    </Provider>
                </ReactNativeKeycloakProvider>
            </NativeBaseProvider>,
        );

        expect(getByTestId('loginBtn')).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know native, but useTheme wraps the render so your rendered components are provided a theme to work with else when you select a theme within your tests there is no theme provider providing those values - i think.